# How do I get IF(AND) to work with multiple conditions?

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm trying to make a page calculator that returns a prescribed value depending on what is input into three dropdown cells.

Dropdown cells are:

- columns (options are 1 or 2);
- trim size (range of options);
- text design (range of options).

I can't seem to get the hang of the IF function. This returns what I want it to:

```
=IF(AND(B7=Sheet1!E2,B8=Sheet1!C2,B9=Sheet1!A2),467,FALSE)
```

But now I need to add a ton of other combinations of columns, trim sizes and text designs, the choices of which will determine which number is returned. Adding another line with one variation at a time doesn't seem to be working, e.g.

```
=IF(AND(B7=Sheet1!E2,B8=Sheet1!C2,B9=Sheet1!A2),467,FALSE), IF(AND(B7=Sheet1!E2,B8=**Sheet1!C3**,B9=Sheet1!A2),570,FALSE)
```

I just get `#VALUE!`

Any advice?

Comment: nest the second in the FALSE space.

Comment: This worked--and then I got to the third condition to nest and I started getting error messages:

=IF(AND(B4=Sheet1!E2,B5=Sheet1!C2,B6=Sheet1!A2),Sheet1!J2,IF(AND(B4=Sheet1!E2,B5=Sheet1!C3,B6=Sheet1!A2),Sheet1!J3, IF(AND(B4=Sheet1!E2,Calculator!B5=Sheet1!C4,Calculator!B6=Sheet1!A2)Sheet1!E3

Is there a limit to how many times you can nest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to nest the If conditions properly with proper syntax - parenthesis, comma need to be accurately placed.

Try adding each If statement in it own line:

```
=IF( AND(B4=Sheet1!E2,B5=Sheet1!C2,B6=Sheet1!A2),
     Sheet1!J2,
       IF(AND(B4=Sheet1!E2,B5=Sheet1!C3,B6=Sheet1!A2),
          Sheet1!J3, 
          IF(AND(B4=Sheet1!E2,Calculator!B5=Sheet1!C4,Calculator!B6=Sheet1!A2),
             Sheet1!E3,
             False
            )
          )
       )
    )
```

**You need to close each bracket properly too**

Above process should help you understand the issue in your formula, But the better way to solve it is using the [Switch Formula](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-function-47ab33c0-28ce-4530-8a45-d532ec4aa25e). It makes nesting conditions easier:

```
=SWITCH(TRUE,
AND(B4=Sheet1!E2,B5=Sheet1!C2,B6=Sheet1!A2), Sheet1!J2,
AND(B4=Sheet1!E2,B5=Sheet1!C3,B6=Sheet1!A2), Sheet1!J3,
AND(B4=Sheet1!E2,Calculator!B5=Sheet1!C4,Calculator!B6=Sheet1!A2), Sheet1!E3,
"If nothing matches - Default"
)
```

the first line in the formula (`=SWITCH(TRUE`) means that, stop searching when you find a condition that is `TRUE`

Comment: I actually fixed my issue by using an INDEX formula instead (muddled my way through it) -- but the SWITCH formula you just shared has helped me solve another problem! Thank you!